Magento: How to ignore linked products in a grouped product with layered filter
I have a question.
I have a filter and its name is "System" and I can select whether I want AP or UP, but when I select the filter AP it also shows some UP grouped products which have products linked with AP, but I don't want it like that.
Example:
I have a grouped product AP 12345 and its attribute "system" is on AP. Then there is a simple product Item1 for AP12345 and its attribute system is on AP and there is another simple product Item2 for AP12345 with the system attribute on UP. Now those two products are linked in the grouped product AP 12345. When I filter now show me systems UP then I don't want to see this grouped product because it's on AP but because of the linked simple products it shows it anyway. How to fix this?
BTW: My Magento is on 2.4.3


plugin beforeAddFieldToFilter
if the attribute is system - change the logic (remove existing filters and add your custom filters in the collection)

if you share / update the question with more specifics - we can identify other solutions.
